# Android - Facebook Login for all users

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on

It might be a duplicated question, but I can't find the answer anywhere (or I can't seem to understand the documentation)...

I am still in the development stage of my app, but I want to let other people use test it (like designers and friends).

To use the Facebook SSO for debugging and developing I entered my `key hash` in the Facebook app management console, but how do I let every user use my app without entering their key hashes?

Do I need to release the app the the Play Store, or is there another way?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837

Comment: Thanks @NguyenDoanTung, but I did all that... I am missing the next steps... what to do I want to release the app to other people?

Comment: Users don't provide any keyhash! You don't have to upload your app to GP, just distribute it

Comment: I agree, but I get an "Invalid key hash" on every device that I didn't add it's key hash to Facebook

Comment: It may be because you use a `release key` instead of `debug key`. I guess you have no problem before building release apk?

Comment: I did have these problems before... And I have both... Shouldn't I? I believe the API says you should put both...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105742/discussion-between-nguyen-doan-tung-and-algosub).